# C++ help understanding partial specialization

Tags: c++, class, templates, partial-specialization

I'm reading some chromium project source code and i found one thing i cant understand, there's a template which take one parameter and partial specialization like below:

```
template <class Sig>
class Callback;

template <typename R, typename A1,typename A2>
class Callback<R(A1,A2)>
{

};
```

Then i can create object like in this examples:

```
Callback < float ( int , string ) > myCallback;
Callback < int ( float , int ) > myCallback2;
etc.
```

I'm trying understand this expression " float (int , string) ", what that means generally? Is it some kind of function signature without name?? I'm totally confused.

Can someone try to explain how it works?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3):

It's a function type. `float(int,string)` describes a function that takes two arguments, one of type `int` and one of type `string`, and returns a `float`.

You can write a typedef for this function type like this:

```
typedef float function_type(int, string);
```

You can do that in C, but in C there is only one thing you could do with a function type: create a pointer to it:

```
void f(function_type*);
```

In C++, such a type can also be used as an argument to a template.

Answer (score 2):

This means it's a callable type that this template needs to be passed, ie a functor or a function pointer or a `std::function<float(int,string)>` in your particular case.

Comment: @ForEveR: I wasn't entirely sure, so I accept that I could have been wrong. I've just deleted that part of my answer

Answer (score 1):

It's the *type* of a function. You may be familiar with function pointers/references already: `int(*)(float, int)` or `int(&)(double)`. Remove the `*` or `&` and you're left with the type: `int(float, int)` or `int(double)`, etc

You can typedef a function type too:

```
typedef int FuncType(short);
FuncType* funcPtr; // pointer to function that takes a short and returns an int
```